# How to parse Array from String in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

My `curl` call looks like

```
curl -v -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -d '{"instanceIds": "[i-081ec3ffa72eb338, i-0c7474fb67bb9043]", "region": "us-west-2a"}' http://localhost:3001/instances/delete
```

and on my `expressJS` based server, the endpoint looks like

```
app.post('/instances/delete', function (req, res) {
  let {region, instanceIds} = req.body;
  console.log(region + "," + instanceIds);
  stopInstances(region, instanceIds)
    .then(function (data) {
      res.send(data);
    })
    .catch(function (reason) {
      res.status(500).send("Error in deleting instances: " + reason);
    });
});
```

The function `stopInstances` looks like

```
export let stopInstances = function (region, instanceIds) {    
  let params = {InstanceIds: instanceIds, DryRun: true};
  console.log(params);
  return ec2.stopInstances(params).promise();
};
```

However, the values are printed as `string`

```
InstanceIds: '[i-081ec3ffa72eb338, i-0c7474fb67bb9043]'
```

How can I convert this into `Array`? I tried `Array.from` but that parses each character

```
Array.from('[i-081ec3ffa72eb338, i-0c7474fb67bb9043]')
(40) ["[", "i", "-", "0", "8", "1", "e", "c", "3", "f", "f", "a", "7", "2", "e", "b", "3", "3", "8", ",", " ", "i", "-", "0", "c", "7", "4", "7", "4", "f", "b", "6", "7", "b", "b", "9", "0", "4", "3", "]"]
```

But I want `[i-081ec3ffa72eb338, i-0c7474fb67bb9043]`

Thanks

Comment: It's a string because you pass a string, you probably want `{"instanceIds": ["i-081ec3ffa72eb338", "i-0c7474fb67bb9043"]...` in your request.

Comment: Thank you for the sharp eyes! I am totally stupid

Comment: Feel free to delete the question

Answer (score 1):

My `curl` call was wrong, based on comment from `georg`, I fixed it to

```
curl -v -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -d '{"instanceIds": ["i-081ec3ffa72eb338", "i-0c7474fb67bb9043"], "region": "us-west-2a"}' http://localhost:3001/instances/delete
```

and that fixed it.

Comment: Instead of answering, just delete. It is not useful for other people than you

Answer (score 0):

You could split the string by comma

```
var parts = your_string.split(",")
```

Then clean the parts, I.e. Remove the braces

```
var cleaned = parts.map( function (part) { 

             return part.replace(/[]/g, "");

});
```

That cleaned variable should now have the parts you want.

Untested, and written from mobile, so you'll probably want to refactor the approach.